# In Eigen what is the result of Sparse / Sparse product or Sparse / Dense product?

Tags: sparse-matrix, eigen

When I multiply two SparseMatrix matrices is the result always a SparseMatrix?
When I multiply a SparseMatrix with a MatrixXd will I always get a MatrixXd as a result? (and vice versa)

Comment: https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialSparse.html this helps

Comment: Technically, the return types are expression templates, which can be assigned to `SparseMatrix` (in the first case) or dense `MatrixXd` (in both cases). Structurally, the product of two sparse matrices can get quite dense.